# How to Stop/Pause and Re Play Bar Animations in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please take a look at this demo and let me know how I can add `stop/pause` and `play` to `.bar` or `#bars` animation?

```js
  $('.bar').stop();

  $("#play").on("click", function () {

  });

  $("#pause").on("click", function () {
      $('#bars').stop();
  });
```

```css
#bars {
    height: 30px;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -30px 0 0 -20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 40px;
}

.bar {
   background: #666;
    bottom: 1px;
    height: 3px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 3px;      
    animation: sound 0ms -800ms linear infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes sound {
    0% {
       opacity: .35;
        height: 3px; 
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;       
        height: 28px;        
    }
}

.bar:nth-child(1)  { left: 1px; animation-duration: 474ms; }
.bar:nth-child(2)  { left: 5px; animation-duration: 433ms; }
.bar:nth-child(3)  { left: 9px; animation-duration: 407ms; }
.bar:nth-child(4)  { left: 13px; animation-duration: 458ms; }
.bar:nth-child(5)  { left: 17px; animation-duration: 400ms; }
.bar:nth-child(6)  { left: 21px; animation-duration: 427ms; }
.bar:nth-child(7)  { left: 25px; animation-duration: 441ms; }
.bar:nth-child(8)  { left: 29px; animation-duration: 419ms; }
.bar:nth-child(9)  { left: 33px; animation-duration: 487ms; }
.bar:nth-child(10) { left: 37px; animation-duration: 442ms; }​
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bars">
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-default" id="play">play</button>
<button class="btn btn-default" id="pause">pause</button>
```

Comment: This is a CSS animation, so `stop` won't work here (as it's for jQuery animations).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's a CSS Animation, you can just override the property with `none` and that will stop the animation, but it won't actually pause it where the animation left.

```js
  $("#play").on("click", function () {
    $('.bar').css('animation', '');
  });

  $("#pause").on("click", function () {
      $('.bar').css('animation', 'none');
  });
```

```css
#bars {
    height: 30px;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -30px 0 0 -20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 40px;
}

.bar {
   background: #666;
    bottom: 1px;
    height: 3px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 3px;      
    animation: sound 0ms -800ms linear infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes sound {
    0% {
       opacity: .35;
        height: 3px; 
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;       
        height: 28px;        
    }
}

.bar:nth-child(1)  { left: 1px; animation-duration: 474ms; }
.bar:nth-child(2)  { left: 5px; animation-duration: 433ms; }
.bar:nth-child(3)  { left: 9px; animation-duration: 407ms; }
.bar:nth-child(4)  { left: 13px; animation-duration: 458ms; }
.bar:nth-child(5)  { left: 17px; animation-duration: 400ms; }
.bar:nth-child(6)  { left: 21px; animation-duration: 427ms; }
.bar:nth-child(7)  { left: 25px; animation-duration: 441ms; }
.bar:nth-child(8)  { left: 29px; animation-duration: 419ms; }
.bar:nth-child(9)  { left: 33px; animation-duration: 487ms; }
.bar:nth-child(10) { left: 37px; animation-duration: 442ms; }​
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bars">
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-default" id="play">play</button>
<button class="btn btn-default" id="pause">pause</button>
```